# How to make PHP session variable persistent?

Tags: php, session

I noticed that including the following lines of PHP code to prevent session fixation or hijacking seem to cause the session variables not to be persistent across pages.

My diagnosis shows that if I remove these lines of code, the session variables would be stored in the session files, which would resolve the session variable persistency issue.

```
<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])) 
{ 
   session_regenerate_id(true); 
   $_SESSION['login'] = 1; 
} 

Additional layers of defense to prevent session hijacking

validate_session($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

// These functions are used to defend against session hijacking

function validate_session($url)
{
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $url) !== 0 ||
        isset($_GET['LOGOUT']) ||
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] !== $_SESSION['PREV_REMOTEADDR'] ||
        $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] !== $_SESSION['PREV_USERAGENT'])
      session_destroy();
    #time-out logic

    session_regenerate_id(true); // generate a new session identifier

    $_SESSION['PREV_USERAGENT'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $_SESSION['PREV_REMOTEADDR'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

?>
```

What could I change to make it work?

Comment: `<?php session_start()...?>`

Comment: I have added session_start(); at the top of all my php files.

Comment: I just tried your code on my local server and noticed that SERVER_NAME is not equal to HTTP_REFERER. HTTP_REFERER has `http://localhost` but SERVER_NAME only has `localhost` (no http://). And you are checking if referer starts with server name.

Comment: You might check and see if the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is properly set by the user agent or browser, otherwise it may invalidate your strpos check.